Difference between vulnerabilityAssessments and sqlVulnerabilityAssessments in Azure SQL
I’m trying to understand the difference between the permissions:
Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/vulnerabilityAssessments and Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/sqlVulnerabilityAssessments.
I need to allow a Function App to set security baselines for SQL databases, but I’m not sure which of these permission is involved in this process. Does the SQL DB Contributor role grant the necessary permissions for this, or is an additional role like SQL Security Manager required?

I think the difference is that vulnerabilityAssessments are the 'classic' configuration while sqlVulnerabilityAssessments are the 'express' configuration - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/defender-for-cloud/sql-azure-vulnerability-assessment-overview and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/defender-for-cloud/sql-azure-vulnerability-assessment-enable  Note that to make baselines, you will already have set up the relevant vulnerability assessment - use that configuration/path as the base. Or just give your Function app access to both types.

Agreed with @seanb, I think the difference at the scope level that  vulnerabilityAssessments  is on the Subscription, Server, Database level while  sqlVulnerabilityAssessments   is on the Subscription, Server level
Now if we check the permissions of both SQL DB Contributor role and SQL Security Manager

SQL DB Contributor role have only Execute vulnerability assessment database scan permission is there on the scope of vulnerabilityAssessments.

SQL Security Manager role have all read write, Execute permission on both scope.


You can give a permission of SQL Security Manager role to your user.
